# Unknown Type name 'NsMutableDictionary'; did you mean 'cfMutableDictionaryRef'? NSDictionary.h

Tags: ios, objective-c

[screenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1eqE.png)**Error:**

```
Unknown Type name 'NsMutableDictionary'; did you mean 'cfMutableDictionaryRef'? NSDictionary.h
```

[image: Error ScreenShot]

Why this happened? How to fix this?

Comment: show some code!

Comment: this error shows in every project.

Comment: may be need to import `NSFoundation`?

Comment: no.....same project works without error in other mac.only my xcode having this erros in every project.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take some time to follow the [Stack Overflow tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Also provide us the relevant code you wrote for your question (You can also read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))

Comment: i removed the xcode and re-install... but the issue is still exists...

Comment: i think you have change code in NSDictionary main file..  copy the working code from other machine and put in the NSDictionary file.

Comment: Thanlkkkkssss @Rushi   its works.... :)

Comment: great....enjoy coding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that was happned because of some accidently removed some code from **NSDictionary** file.